# Linq in MVC complaining about missing references

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to work in `MVC3` using `linq` to extract a list of names from an XML file.

```
List<String> firstNames = (from p in x.Descendants("Row")
                           orderby p.Element("id").Value
                           select p.Element("firstName").Value).ToList();
```

The compiler keeps complaining:

```
Error   1   
   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for 
   source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.
   'OrderBy' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a 
   using directive for 'System.Linq'
```

I've checked and the `System.Core` is in the references folder and there is a `using System.Linq;` statement in the file.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your code

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```